# The date fetched from database is displayed wrong

Tags: android

I am new to android and I am stuck at one place. I wanted to fetch the date from `mysql` database and display it in android app.

The code for android application

```
 try {
JSONArray data = response.getJSONArray("std");
String result[]=new String[data.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++)
{
    JSONObject obj = data.getJSONObject(i);
    name = obj.getString("Name");
    fromdate=obj.getString("From");
    todate = obj.getString("To");
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    Date fd=formatter.parse(fromdate);
   cal.setTime(fd);
   from1=cal.getTimeInMillis();
   Date td=formatter.parse(todate);
   cal.setTime(td);
   to1=cal.getTimeInMillis();              
   date= DateUtils.formatDateRange( Main2Activity.this, from1, to1,  
     DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_YEAR );
   result[i]=""+name+"\n"+date;
  }
```

JSON FILE

```
<?php
$result=mysqli_query($link,"select * from oTrip");
$data=array();
$rows=mysqli_num_rows($result);
while($rec=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$data[]=$rec;
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array("std" =>$data));
?>
```

And the output is

[image]

Please help out with this!!
Thank You.

Comment: Add your Json response.

Comment: @whenthemorningcomes DateUtils is Api class of `android.text.format `package .

Comment: My bad. Thanks^^

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35760788/dateutils-formatdaterange-issues-when-formatting-date-range) out.

Comment: @whenthemorningcomes it didnt worked out.

Comment: @ADM  $result=mysqli_query($link,"select * from oTrip");
$data=array();
$rows=mysqli_num_rows($result);
while($rec=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$data[]=$rec;
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array("std" =>$data));

Comment: @kruti Kravade provide your json response

Comment: $result=mysqli_query($link,"select * from oTrip"); $data=array(); $rows=mysqli_num_rows($result); while($rec=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { $data[]=$rec; } header('Content-Type: application/json'); echo json_encode(array("std" =>$data));  @kamalverma

Comment: echo json_encode(array("std" =>$data));   , provide its echo string,that you are using to parse json data

Comment: MySQL default date format is 'yyyy-MM-dd'. Have you checked that ?

Comment: @t0mm13b yes i know...

Comment: @KrutiKarvade You were asked to supply the JSON, you still have not. Why? If you knew of the default format, why did you not format it in such a way that it can be easily consumed. *Hint:* use ISO8601 formatting before putting it into a JSON, makes life so much easier and avoid any date parsing issues.

Comment: are you getting to date and from date in milliseconds?

Comment: @t0mm13b just look I have updated it. And I wanted to have the display in dd-mm-yyyy format

Comment: @RituSumanMohanty yes

Comment: @KrutiKarvade where is the JSON? All you updated in this question is the 
 php code. Show us the actual data.

Comment: what is the format of date stored in your database? And how do you want to display it?

Comment: @global_warming in database it is stored in yyyy-MM-dd and i want to display the date range in dd-mm-yyyy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
 JSONObject obj = data.getJSONObject(i);
 name = obj.getString("Name");
 fromdate=obj.getString("From");
 todate = obj.getString("To");
 DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
 Date fd=formatter.parse(fromdate);
 Date td=formatter.parse(todate);
 DateFormat newFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
 String newFromdate = newFormatter.format(fd);
 String newTodate = newFormatter.format(td);
 date = newFromdate + " - " + newTodate;
 result[i]=""+name+"\n"+date;
```

You have to parse date in given `JSON` format and then change that parsed date into new format using another `formatter`.

You can use one-liners as:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
DateFormat newFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
fromdate = newFormatter.format(formatter.parse(fromdate));
todate = newFormatter.format(formatter.parse(todate));
```

Answer (score 0):

Change "dd-MM-yyyy" to "dd/MM/yyyy"

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this,

```
 fromdate=obj.getLong("From");
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm dd/MM/yyyy");
     sdf.format(new Date(fromdate));
```

Comment: This is not helping..can you suggest something else?

Comment: it's working in my case you show me your from date value

Comment: so for using long i have to store date in database in bigint format?