# DateUtils.formatDateRange does not respect Locale for Formatter

Tags: java, android, polish

I am trying to display text for my date using `DateUtils.formatDateRange()` method with below option:

```
DateTime time = new DateTime().withYear(year).withMonthOfYear(month).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
Locale locale = new Locale("pl");
Formatter formatter = new Formatter(locale);

String title = DateUtils.formatDateRange(getContext(), formatter, time.getMillis(), time.getMillis(),
                    DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE | DateUtils.FORMAT_NO_MONTH_DAY | DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_YEAR).toString();
```

I expect to have below results (in Polish):

> Czerwiec 2020

but I am getting:

> June 2020

Anyone have an idea what can be the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DateUtils.formatDateRange() issues when formatting date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35760788/dateutils-formatdaterange-issues-when-formatting-date-range)

Comment: SimpleDateFormat doesn't handle my case in this scenario

Comment: How about this link?[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21257014/set-language-to-french-in-android-datepickerdialog)

Comment: @K.Os SDF as well as JSR310 can print the same thing that would print, and unlike apache-commons, it's not a third party dep, is not crazy API, and does adhere to locale standards.